# Filtered table showing rows outside filter range

Tags: excel, filter

I have a large table in Excel (36,000+ rows), whenever I apply a filter using the drop-down filter button in the header excel will return between 1-4 rows that do not contain anything that's specified in the filter. Regardless of which column I filter, or if I apply multiple filters there are consistently 1-3 rows showing that should not be displayed.

In the example below I filtered for "Jasp", hence the last row should not be shown, but for some reason it always appears. When I apply additional filters that should also exclude this row it still remains visible.

[image]

Comment: The row is not a part of filtered range (color of row number is different). Try to remove/apply again autofilter. If it doesn't work, check if there are some empty rows in the table.

Comment: I've tried this many times, but it does not make a difference. I've also tried selecting the entire table and removing/adding the filters. Nothing seems to work...